# Where vs property specification

Tags: neo4j

Trying to understand when to use a property value vs a WHERE clause.

```
$Match (g:GROUP {GroupID: 1}) RETURN g
```

gives the expected response (all reported properties as expected).

And,

```
$match (a:ADDRESS {AddressID: 454}) return a
```

gives the expected response (all reported properties as expected).

However, the combo in a MERGE

```
MERGE (g:GROUP {GroupID: 1})-[r:USES]->(a:ADDRESS {AddressID: 454}) Return g.ShortName, type(r), a.Line1;
```

creates two new nodes (with no properties, of course, except a redundant AddressID and GroupID. The AddressID and GroupID were created with toInt() and I tried putting the property values in toInt() also (same result):

[Added 2 labels, created 2 nodes, set 2 properties, created 1 relationship, returned 1 row in 77 ms.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKt2P.png)

So, after DETACH DELETE the extraneous nodes, I try again with (which works)

```
Match (g:GROUP) WHERE g.GroupID = 1
Match (a:ADDRESS) WHERE a.AddressID = 454
MERGE (g)-[r:USES]->(a)
RETURN g.ShortName, type(r), a.Line1
```

[Returned 1 row in 14 ms.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i96tE.png)

WHY does the separate MATCHing work while the property spec does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MERGE is one of the trickier clauses for exactly this behavior.

From the Cypher documentation for MERGE:

> When using MERGE on full patterns, the behavior is that either the
>   whole pattern matches, or the whole pattern is created. MERGE will not
>   partially use existing patterns — it’s all or nothing. If partial
>   matches are needed, this can be accomplished by splitting a pattern up
>   into multiple MERGE clauses.

So when you're going to MERGE a pattern, and you aren't using variables bound to already existing nodes, then the entire pattern is matched, or if it doesn't exist, the entire pattern is created, which, in your case, creates duplicate nodes, as your intent is to use existing nodes in the MERGE.

In general, when you want to MERGE a relationship or pattern between nodes that already exist, it's best to MATCH or MERGE on the nodes which should already exist first, and then MERGE the pattern with the matched or merged variables.

EDIT

I think there's some confusion here about the reasons for the differences in the queries.

This doesn't have anything to do with whether the properties are defined in a WHERE clause, or inline on the nodes in the MATCH clauses.

In fact, you can do this just fine with your last query, and it will behave identically:

```
Match (g:GROUP {GroupID:1})
Match (a:ADDRESS {AddressID:454})
MERGE (g)-[r:USES]->(a)
RETURN g.ShortName, type(r), a.Line1
```

The reasons for the differences, again, the behavior of MERGE

Really the easiest way to grasp what's going on is to consider what the behavior would be if MERGE were substituted first with MATCH, and then if no match was found, with CREATE.

```
MATCH (g)-[r:USES]->(a)
```

and if there is no match, it does CREATE instead

```
CREATE (g)-[r:USES]->(a)
```

That should make sense...a CREATE with existing nodes will create the missing part, the relationship.

Contrast that with using MERGE on the entire pattern:

```
MERGE (g:GROUP {GroupID: 1})-[r:USES]->(a:ADDRESS {AddressID: 454}) 
Return g.ShortName, type(r), a.Line1;
```

First this will attempt a MATCH:

```
MATCH (g:GROUP {GroupID: 1})-[r:USES]->(a:ADDRESS {AddressID: 454})
```

and then when no match is found, a CREATE

```
CREATE (g:GROUP {GroupID: 1})-[r:USES]->(a:ADDRESS {AddressID: 454})
```

And given what we know of how CREATE works, it doesn't attempt to match parts of the pattern (and there are no variables that have already matched to existing elements of the graph), it creates the pattern as a whole, creating a brand new :GROUP and :ADDRESS node with the given properties, and the new :USES relationship.

Comment: I updated my answer with a better explanation of how MERGE is working.

Comment: So MERGE isn't its own process. It is a concatenation of a logical MATCH test and, if false, a standard CREATE process. Specifying variables outside (before) the MERGE command is necessary for the values to be usable in the CREATE process.

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE (g:GROUP {GroupID: 1})-[r:USES]->(a:ADDRESS {AddressID: 454}) Return g.ShortName, type(r), a.Line1;` most likely creates two nodes, because those properties (GroupID for the GROUP node / AddressID for ADDRESS node) are not the only properties on those nodes.

Matching the nodes first ensures that you're getting nodes with matching properties (which could have other properties, too) and merge those.

If you had an index with uniqueness constraint on both GroupID for GROUP nodes and AddressID for ADDRESS nodes, then the MERGE without matching first, should still make that connection.

Comment: Will try with indices in a few days.  I haven't created any indices yet. Have one more set of data to upload.  Probably could have created them all along. Have been loading a set, verifying, do backup then repeat for the next set. Trying to minimize the amount of rework for learning curve misunderstandings, like this one.

Comment: Due to the behavior of MERGE, the only thing a uniqueness constraint would do is cause the query to fail because it was trying to create nodes with those properties. You can try this on your own instance. Using indexes or uniqueness constraints is a good idea for speeding up the initial matches, though, even if that won't solve the MERGE issue.